# How can I determine the burden of an image resizer on our server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

We have a need to re-size large images to a smaller size before they go down to the end user.  (End users are global and can be on slow connections.)  The main server, a portal server(plumtree), generates the image link for the user's browser and the browser then requests the image from a different server (Aqualogic).

Unfortunately the AL server doesn't always have the smaller copy of the file, because the re-size process has been manual in the past and hasn't happened with regularity.

To remove the manual step from the need, I created a simple HttpHandler web site on yet a 3rd server which takes the requested image, goes to the AquaLogic server with a WebRequest and downloads the full size image, re-sizes it on the fly and then sends the result down to the requesting user's browser.

Now my boss is asking me what the impact on the 3rd server (which is our production web server cluster) will be.  He wants metrics on processing load and bandwidth usage.  How can I measure this?  CAN I measure this?

Comment: Have you considered using an [optimized, server-safe library like ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net)? HttpHandlers [have inherent performance limitations](http://www.hanselminutes.com/313/deep-inside-image-resizing-and-scaling-with-aspnet-and-iis-with-imageresizingnet-author-na).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bandwidth usage should be simple to approximate if you keep track of the size of the original image and the size of the resized image.

There are profiling tools available that can help you determine the processing load such as [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).